# Matching strings with Regular Expressions c#

Tags: c#, regex

The program is given a String for the name of a cell in a spreadsheet. This spreadsheet can contain a cell with a name that starts with a letter a-zA-Z_ this has to be the case, anything else is invalid. After the first letter or underscore there can be any combination of letters numbers or underscores. For example:

`______35we3I` Is a valid name

`123dfdf` Is NOT a valid name.

If these strings exist I want to throw an exception. I am new to regular expressions but this is what I came up with and it doesn't work like I want it to.

```
@"[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_|\d]*"
```

When The second example is passed in the `Regex.IsMatch` function returns true because the last half of the expression is valid. Is there a way to start from the beginning of the string always?

I should say that I tried using the {^} to acomplish the above condition but it doesnt accept anything when the carrot is there.

Comment: Seems fine to me, just tested it with adding the start and end of the expression: here's the link http://rubular.com/r/UMIcvl0olc

Comment: Avinash gave good advices. I just want to add something : to test your regexes, you can use RadSoftware regex designer ( http://rad-software-regular-expression-designer.software.informer.com/1.4/ ), it's very powerful and since it's built in .Net, it gives exactly the same option than .Net regex classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the start and end anchors and you don't need to put `|` inside the character class. `|` inside the char class would match a literal `|` symbol.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*$"
```

Code:

```
String s = "123dfdf";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*$")) {
Console.WriteLine("Error! Wrong format.");
}
else {
Console.WriteLine("Correct format.");
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/g4Wion)

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess im just using the wrong website to test my regex.

Answer (score 2):

For testing your regex, you've a very good website [here](http://regexpal.com)

For your regex, you want to add a number validator in your regex:

```
@"^[0-9a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*"
```

with this, your two strings was validate.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_\d]*"
```

with this, just string started by not a number was validate.

Comment: op don't want a number to be present at first.

Comment: oh, sorry for my mistake, thank for your response :p

Comment: `|` inside a character class would match a literal `|` symbol.